# calculate the mean of different subsets based on the same ID in a dataframe and store the results in a new dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, dataframe, mean

My dataframe (hh_dist_points) has the following structure:

```
hh_dist_points <- read.table(header=TRUE ,text="
  hhid VillageID hhid_1 VillageI_1    NEAR_DIST
  2739 405050508   2730  405050508 8.300739e+01
  2739 405050508   2588  405050508 9.717326e+01
  2739 405050508   2825  405050508 1.335821e+02
  2739 405050508   2823  405050508 1.631118e+02
  2739 405050508   2729  405050508 1.964680e+02
  2739 405050508   2810  405050508 2.243312e+02
  2739 405050508   2828  405050508 2.889768e+02
  2739 405050508   2725  405050502 8.808605e+02
  2739 405050508   2822  405050502 9.084585e+02
  2739 405050508   2731  405050502 9.222313e+02
  2739 405050508   2742  405050502 9.681594e+02
  2739 405050508   2741  405050502 1.026474e+03")
```

The original dataset containts ca. 2000 observations (1 observation = a house in a village (hhid). Houses which belong to the same village have the same VillageID (ca. 10 observations with the same ID). 
Near_Dist: geodetical distance between 2 houses (hhid)
The dataframe above shows the distance of each house (hhid) to all other houses in my dataset (hhid_1) (together over 3 Mio. rows).

My objective:
Calculate the mean of Near_Dist for yeach group of observations (hhid) based on the same VillageID and store the result in a new dataframe:

```
VillageID   dist_mean
405050508   963,257416
405050502   823,21464
.....       .........
```

General idea: If VillageID = VillageID_1 then calculate the mean of Near_Dist and store the result in a new dataframe.

My idea was to use a loop:

```
if(hh_dist_points$VillageID = hh_dist_points$VillageI_1) {
hh_dist_new <- mean(hh_dist$NEAR_DIST)
}
else
```

But I know this isn´t correct (and unfinished) but I don´t know how to finish it. 
Any ideas how to simply solve this problem? (maybe without using loops).
I tried to search for any answers and solutions but I haven´t found any.

I need the dataframe for other calculations.
Many thanks four your help.

Comment: Your 'hh_dist_points$VillageID = hh_dist_points$VillageI_1' needs to be '==' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
 require(dplyr)

 new_data  <- hh_dist_points %>%
  filter_("VillageID == VillageI_1") %>%
  group_by(VillageID) %>%
  summarise(dist_mean=mean(NEAR_DIST, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do it in R base, it easy to do it with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)


hh_dist_points <- read.table(header=TRUE ,text="
      hhid VillageID hhid_1 VillageI_1    NEAR_DIST
      2739 405050508   2730  405050508 8.300739e+01
      2739 405050508   2588  405050508 9.717326e+01
      2739 405050508   2825  405050508 1.335821e+02
      2739 405050508   2823  405050508 1.631118e+02
      2739 405050508   2729  405050508 1.964680e+02
      2739 405050508   2810  405050508 2.243312e+02
      2739 405050508   2828  405050508 2.889768e+02
      2739 405050508   2725  405050502 8.808605e+02
      2739 405050508   2822  405050502 9.084585e+02
      2739 405050508   2731  405050502 9.222313e+02
      2739 405050508   2742  405050502 9.681594e+02
      2739 405050508   2741  405050502 1.026474e+03")


dt <- data.table(hh_dist_points)
dt[VillageID==VillageI_1,mean(NEAR_DIST,na.rm=TRUE),.(VillageID)]

#  VillageID       V1
# 1: 405050508 169.5215
```

Comment: It´s just by VillageID.When I run the code I get the error: "Error: unexpected ',' in "dt[,mean(NEAR_DIST,na.rm=TRUE)],"

Comment: sorry I didn't test the code before. I corrected it.

Comment: I have just edited your answer with the results from the generated dataframe. The results are wrong. (I need mean for obs. where VillageID = VillageI_1).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right this will work:

```
require(dplyr)
newDF<- hh_dist_points%>%
    group_by(VillageID, Village_I1)%>%
    summarize(average=mean(NEAR_DIST))
```

This will create a new data frame called newDF with your VillageID and VIllageI1 columns, then add a column named average with the mean of the values in NEAR_DIST for each village_ID and Village_I1 combination.

Then you can use:

```
finalDF<- newDF[newDF$Village_ID == newDF$Village_I1,]
```

This will subset keeping only the rows where the two columns of ID's are equal. it. This keeps you out of a loop and is pretty fast and easy to understand the logic.

If I misunderstood you and that is not what you are looking for, shoot me a comment explaining how, and I will refine the answer.

Comment: After running your code I get the following warning messages: Warning messages:    1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'Village_ID'. 
    2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'Village_I1'.

Comment: Try cutting and pasting the name of the data frame, and the two columns from your code, in case I spelled it wrong or there was an added space somewhere. If that does not work, run `str(hh_dist_points)` and put the results in a `EDIT:` then comment here and I will try to see what might be wrong.

Comment: You just forget one bracket by summarize `summarize(average=mean(NEAR_DIST))` but it functions well. I have made some subsets of different VillageIDs to control the distances but it seems everything correct... Many thanks!

Comment: sorry...I tested it on my own data and cut and pasted, must have cut too much! I will fix it for the next person!